# "This webpage is not available" error after altering /www directory

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I built the login functionality for a website on an AWS ec2 ubuntu with LAMP setup and it was working fine. The PHP files for this were located in /var/www/html. Then, to also allow login from an android device, I added and began working on the directory android_login_api in the /www folder. After adding several files and directories to this I noticed the website was no longer working and displayed "This webpage is not available" when I attempted to reach it. Despite completely removing android_login_api and attempting to revert the directory /www to just the way it was when it worked, this error remains.

I have spent a few days searching for a solution, but most answers pertain to the setup of apache which was already working fine for me. I tried restarting apache but neither index.php nor any other files I specify can be reached. I have also spent a lot of time trying to edit apache .conf files but with no luck.

Any ideas about what may have happened or if there is a specific path I need but may have accidentally altered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of access problems are caused by incorrect configuration of **Virtual Hosts** which seems like the problem here.

As you mentioned, the readable directory was `/var/www/html` and then you tried to access `/var/www/android_login_api`, which is not accessible by default and is specified in your virtual host file for the website. Location: `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

If you have done it different to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts#create-the-first-virtual-host-file), it will be difficult for anyone to help you. Don't create hosts in `apache.conf`. Read it before reading my answer further.

When you make changes to the virtual host, don't forget to use `sudo a2ensite yoursite.com.conf` as well as restarting apache service with `sudo service apache2 restart` after enabling the site.

The last thing that you should know about setting up websites is **www directory owner**. When you done making changes to files via FTP or SSH, run `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R`. **www-data** is the username like **root** used by Apache to allow external access. Otherwise the fiels will be accessible only with 0755 permissions by any other user and not 0644.

This is just a bunch of things essential to make changes and work with HTTP servers. Though my answer is not clear and I'm unable to point out your issue, I believe I've given you additional knowlege/consideration points to troubleshoot your issue. Drop a comment for more specifics.